# When to use article 'a' before 'most'?

Tags: articles

I found a sentence in the dictionary:
'He walked off in a most bizarre fashion.' I found in the grammar books, it is a rule to use 'the' before superlative degree.

Now, I'm confused when I should use article 'a' before 'most'.

Comment: @FumbleFinger, I can't understand how this example mentioned above is different from that example : 'He is the most brilliant student in the class.'?

Comment: If you can't see the difference between ***the most** brilliant student* and ***a** brilliant student* you should definitely be asking on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), not here.

Comment: When *most* takes an indefinite rather than a definite article it is a mere intensifier and not part of a superlative.

Comment: Remove "most" from the sentence and re-evaluate.  If "a" (or "an") is appropriate ahead of the term modified by "most" (and the sentence otherwise reads OK) then the "a" is appropriate there when "most" is in place.  In some cases "the" *may* be used instead, as an additional emphasis, but it's not required.

Comment: Why is this a duplicate question? It is way more specific than the linked one, where a distinction between superlatives and elatives isn’t even mentioned. Brian’s point is crucial here.